# Grafana clock panel manual installation

Tags: grafana

I have installed Grafana on Windows Server 2016 and it's runing as a Service.
Because my server is behind proxy server and i didn't find where i can setup proxy server in custom.ing i approach to manual installation of Grafana clock panel. The server it self has internet, but not Grafana.

From command line i tried with:

grafana-cli --pluginsDir C:\grafana-6.1.6\data\plugins\grafana-clock-panel plugins install grafana-clock-panel-6fdc3d5

but i get error:

Failed to send request: Get https://grafana.com/api/plugins/repo/grafana-clock-panel-6fdc3d5: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[31mError[0m: [31m✗[0m Failed to send request. error: Get https://grafana.com/api/plugins/repo/grafana-clock-panel-6fdc3d5: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: Did you check these : firewall ? Windows access ?Permissions ? Port Number ? This current

Comment: Firewall, check, Windows access, check, Permissions, check, Port Number, check. Everything is OK.

Comment: I have resolved my problem. You can see solution here: https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-clock-plugin/17193?u=skocev